# Auto serialize Entity Framework entities WCF

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, wcf, wcf-serialization

It is possible to "auto" serialize all entities from a database when solution is build? (I use WCF, WPF and Entity Framework 6)

I observed that some of entities are serialized without doing anything.

In Service Reference configuration (at client) is checked reuse types in all referenced assemblies.

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "serialize"?

Comment: @IlyaChumakov Maybe I'm wrong but I think that attached image can help you  to make an idea about what I mean.  sesizari, interventii and piese interventii are all entities from my Data Model but I have more entities in data model that are not exposed in my WPF project.